# How to force a .trigger(...) immediately?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a button that does some heavy computation and in between the computation-steps I want to refresh the page.

**JavaScript:**

```
.on('click', function() {
    // compute something

    jQuery('#page')
        .trigger('pageshow')
    ;

    // compute something

    jQuery('#page')
        .trigger('pageshow')
    ;

    // compute something
}
```

This sadly doesn't work, because the `pageshow`-event is triggered, after `.on(click)` has finished.

Is there any way to force the execution of `.trigger(...)` immediately?

**JavaScript - ugly solution:**

```
.on('click', function() {
    // compute something

    window.setTimeout(function() {
        // compute something

        jQuery('#page')
            .trigger('pageshow')
        ;

        window.setTimeout(function() {
            // compute something

            jQuery('#page')
                .trigger('pageshow')
            ;
        }, 1);
    }, 1);
}
```

The ugly solution would work, but is really quite ugly. One also has to implement a check whether the `.on('click', ...)`-event is fully computed when being triggered.

**JavaScript - prettier, but still ugly solution:**

```
var functionFirst = function() {
    // compute something

    jQuery('#page')
        .trigger('pageshow')
    ;

    window.setTimeout(functionSecond, 1);
};

var functionSecond = function() {
    // compute something

    jQuery('#page')
        .trigger('pageshow')
    ;

    window.setTimeout(functionThird, 1);
};

var functionThird = function() {
    // compute something

    jQuery('#idJqGame')
        .trigger('pageshow')
    ;
};

window.setTimeout(functionFirst, 1);
```

The prettier, but still ugly solution basically does the same thing as the ugly one - it is just easier to read and therefore I am usint this one so far.

Comment: Does window.setTimeout(jQuery('#page').trigger('pageshow'), 1) help?     code passed in the settimeout would be taken out of the code flow execution.

Comment: It sadly won't work like that. I've added an ugly solution how it would work using .setTimeout(...) - but it is just way to ugly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript interpreter is build around an "event loop". Due to this design and as the interpreter is ran in a single thread, all events are handled *sequentially*.

If it is possible in your application design, try to do a regular call for the page refresh instead of an event.

Another option, if you can guarantee that your application will only be ran on modern browsers, is to move the "heavy computations" to a web-worker. More informations here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_web_workers

EDIT 1:

According to the section 'Nested Events' of http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/timing-and-synchronization-in-javascript/, It may be possible to achieve what you want provided that you use the native browser functions to queue your events

Another elegant solution could be to take advantage of the sequential handling of events. Move you 'heavy computation' to an event handler. Then alternatively push 'compute' and 'pageshow' events so that they will be alternatively called.
This said, I'm afraid this will cause the page to look unresponsive as regular DOM events will also be queued *after*.

EDIT 2:

Just found this: http://api.jquery.com/queue/ Might help.

Comment: Thanks for your reply - unfortunately I am already aware of all the things you have mentioned and neither regular page refreshs, nor web-workers are an option for me.

Comment: @SimonN. Does my edit brings you new options ? What you try to achieve closely deals with JavaScript's internal...

Comment: Thanks again - dispatchEvent will only work combined with createEvent and as I don't know how to create a pageshow-event I am somewhat stuck. Creating my own compute-events isn't an option either, since I still need to prevent multiple clicks. Finally jQuery.queue(...) should only be used for visual effects.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry to say that the ugly solution is the best one.
It can be prettified, but the bottom line is that you need to break your code into smaller blocks in order to have the possibility to control them.

Comment: That's pretty damn sad - at least now I know that there isn't a 'good' solution. Thanks guys!